# Ajuda em montar uma lambda a partir de um foreach

Tags: c#, linq, expressões-lambda

Tenho esse `foreach`:

```
foreach (var row in responseObject)
{
    if (row.CDOrigem == request.CentroDeDistribuicaoId)
    {
        if (row.FaixasPreco == null || row.FaixasPreco.Count() == 0)
        {
            var uniqueItem = new ConsultarPrecoFaixaResponse();
            uniqueItem.PrecoBRL = row.ValorProduto;
            uniqueItem.PrecoUSD = row.ValorDolar;
            uniqueItem.CodigoMoeda = row.CodigoMoeda;
            faixaPrecoResponse.Add(uniqueItem);
        }
        else
        {
            foreach (var faixaPreco in row.FaixasPreco)
            {
                decimal cotacaoCalculada = 1;
                if (row.CodigoMoeda != CODIGO_MOEDA_REAL)
                    cotacaoCalculada = row.ValorProduto / row.ValorDolar;

                var faixaPrecoItem = new ConsultarPrecoFaixaResponse();
                if (row.CodigoMoeda != CODIGO_MOEDA_REAL)
                {
                    faixaPrecoItem.PrecoBRL = faixaPreco.Preco * cotacaoCalculada;
                    faixaPrecoItem.PrecoUSD = faixaPreco.Preco;
                }
                else
                {
                    faixaPrecoItem.PrecoBRL = faixaPreco.Preco;
                    faixaPrecoItem.PrecoUSD = 0;
                }

                faixaPrecoItem.CodigoMoeda = row.CodigoMoeda;
                faixaPrecoItem.QtdeMinimo = faixaPreco.Minimo;
                faixaPrecoItem.QtdeMaximo = faixaPreco.Maximo;
                faixaPrecoResponse.Add(faixaPrecoItem);
            }
        }
        break;
    }
}
```

A partir disso, comecei a escrever essa lambda

```
var qry = responseObject.Where(obj => obj.CDOrigem == request.CentroDeDistribuicaoId)
```

Veja que esse Where tem a ver com o primeiro if dentro do foreach, mas a partir daí comecei a ficar com dúvida para seguir. Não precisa código, apenas orientação em como seguir em frente, em relação aos demais if's e etc..

**EDIT1**

Dessa forma é o caminho correto?

```
var qry = responseObject
                .Where(obj => obj.CDOrigem == request.CentroDeDistribuicaoId)
                .Where(row => row.FaixasPreco == null || row.FaixasPreco.Count() == 0)
                .Select(sel => new ConsultarPrecoFaixaResponse
                {
                    PrecoBRL = sel.ValorProduto,
                    PrecoUSD = sel.ValorDolar,
                    CodigoMoeda = sel.CodigoMoeda,
                })
```

**EDIT2**

Baseado na resposta do João Martins, fiz dessa forma e agora vem os valores dos produtos, mas continua lento

```
var qry1 = from ro in responseObject
           .SelectMany(r => r.FaixasPreco, (ro, fp) => new { ro, fp })
                       select new ConsultarPrecoFaixaResponse()
                       {
                           PrecoBRL = (ro.ro.FaixasPreco == null || ro.ro.FaixasPreco.Count() == 0 ? ro.ro.ValorProduto : (ro.ro.CodigoMoeda == CODIGO_MOEDA_REAL ? ro.fp.Preco : (ro.fp.Preco * (ro.ro.ValorProduto / ro.ro.ValorDolar)))),
                           PrecoUSD = (ro.ro.FaixasPreco == null || ro.ro.FaixasPreco.Count() == 0 ? ro.ro.ValorDolar : (ro.ro.CodigoMoeda == CODIGO_MOEDA_REAL ? 0 : ro.fp.Preco)),
                           CodigoMoeda = ro.ro.CodigoMoeda,
                           QtdeMinimo = ro.fp.Minimo,
                           QtdeMaximo = ro.fp.Maximo
                       };

            faixaPrecoResponse.AddRange(qry1);
```

Comment: Fiz uma edição, mas daquela forma está errada. Preciso de join ou coisas assim?

Comment: Tirei o **ConsultarPrecoFaixaResponse** e fiz um select new anônimo e acrescentei outra propriedade como FaixasPreco, aí posso seguir com o Where diferente de null e count() maior que 0

Comment: Isso pode depender muito da quantidade de informação que tem para devolver!

Answer (score 1):

Acho que é capaz de conseguir desta forma:

```
var qry =  from ro in responseObject
           where ro.FaixasPreco == null || ro.FaixasPreco.Count() == 0
           select new ConsultarPrecoFaixaResponse()
           {
               PrecoBRL = ro.ValorProduto,
               PrecoUSD = ro.ValorDolar,
               CodigoMoeda = ro.CodigoMoeda
           };

var qry1 =  from ro in responseObject.Where(r => r.FaixasPreco != null && r.FaixasPreco.Count() > 0)
            .SelectMany(r => r.FaixasPreco, (ro, fp) => new { ro, fp })
            select new ConsultarPrecoFaixaResponse()
            {
                PrecoBRL = (ro.ro.CodigoMoeda == CODIGO_MOEDA_REAL ? fp.Preco : (fp.Preco * (ro.ValorProduto/ro.ValorDolar))),
                PrecoUSD = (ro.ro.CodigoMoeda == CODIGO_MOEDA_REAL ? 0 : fp.Preco),
                CodigoMoeda = ro.ro.CodigoMoeda,
                QtdeMinimo = fp.Minimo,
                QtdeMaximo = fp.Maximo
            };
```

Se o resultado a devolver for uma junção dos dois resultados, podemos juntá-los desta forma:

```
var qry2 = qry.Union(qry1);
```

Comment: Uma dúvida: O return do método todo é esse: `return new ConsultarPrecoReader(faixaPrecoResponse);` e como atribuo essas duas Linqs no return do método, como faço isso? Devo fazer isso: `faixaPrecoResponse.AddRange(qry);
 faixaPrecoResponse.AddRange(qry1);`

Comment: Resposta editada para incluir o retorno :)

Comment: O problema é que os valores na lambda estão vindo zerados e se volto ao foreach, vem valor e continua demorando, essa eu não entendi ainda

Comment: Mas devolve os registos corretos? Só os valores é que ficam mal?

Comment: Talvez um left join com os preços eu consiga, acho eu

Comment: Se a classe `FaixasPreco` tiver uma coluna de ligação com a `responseObject` sim, consegue fazer por `JOIN`!